# Loop through the list of dynamically added input type radio list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a function `MultiChoiceQues(theSeq, theQues, theChoices theAns)`. I then add the `theQues` in a `p` tag followed by the unordered list of all the respective options with an input of type radio for each option.

In an array variable `allQues[]` I created multiple instance for the function `MultiChoiceQues` passing different arguments. Now, on load I'm showing all the questions with their respective options.

How can I access and highlight all the correct answers?

```js
var content = "";

function MultiChoiceQues(theSeq, theQues, theChoices, theAns) {
  content += '<p>' + theQues + '</p> <ul>';

  theChoices.forEach(function(eachChoice) {
    content += '<li><input type="radio" name="' + theSeq + '"/> ' + eachChoice + '</li>';
  });
  content += '</ul>';
  return content;

  console.log(content);
}

var allQues = [
  new MultiChoiceQues(1, "Who is Prime Minister of England?", ["Obama", "Blair", "Brown", "Cameron"], 4),

  new MultiChoiceQues(2, "What is the Capital of Brazil?", ["São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Brasília", "Salvador"], 3),

  new MultiChoiceQues(3, "Who won the French open 2016 in Men’s Single category?", ["Novak Djokovic", "Andy Murray", "Rafael Nadal"], 1)
];

function ShowAllQues() {
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = content;
}

function ShowAllAns() {
  /* Highlight all the correct answers */
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #f2f2f3;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #0193b7;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5bb12f;
}
#container {
  border: 10px solid #293e6a;
  padding: 0 0 20px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #c4c4c4;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Eras ITC';
  color: #e792b5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.flyingButton {
  position: fixed;
  right: 18px;
  top: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #293e6a;
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  border: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flyingButton:hover {
  background: #0193b7;
}
.flyingButton:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="ShowAllQues();">
  <div id="container">
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="Answers" class="flyingButton" onclick="ShowAllAns();   return false;">
</body>
```

Comment: Really liking the design!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the getAnswer method to your MultiChoiceQues constructor.

```
function MultiChoiceQues(theSeq, theQues, theChoices, theAns) {
  content += '<p>' + theQues + '</p> <ul>';

  theChoices.forEach(function(eachChoice) {
    content += '<li><input type="radio" name="'+ theSeq +'"/> ' + eachChoice + '</li>';
  });

  content+='</ul>';


  this.getAnswer = function () {
      return theAns;
  }
}
```

Then this is your answers function.

```
function ShowAllAns(){
    /* Highlight all the correct answers */

    var answers = allQues.map(function (question) {
        return question.getAnswer();
    })

    var question_lists = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < question_lists.length; i++) {
        var answer_index = answers[i];
        var items = question_lists[i].childNodes;

        items[answer_index - 1].style.background = "red";
    } 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1prr4m7f/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this with jQuery:

```js
   var content="";
    function MultiChoiceQues(theSeq, theQues, theChoices, theAns) {
       content += '<p>' + theQues + '</p> <ul>';
       theChoices.forEach(function(eachChoice,index) {
       if(index == theAns-1){
           content += '<li class="options answer"><input type="radio" name="'+ theSeq +'"/> ' + eachChoice + '</li>';
      }else{
           content += '<li class="options"><input type="radio" name="'+ theSeq +'"/> ' + eachChoice + '</li>';
      }
    });
    content+='</ul>';
    return content;
    }

    var allQues = [
     new MultiChoiceQues(1, "Who is Prime Minister of England?", ["Obama", "Blair", "Brown", "Cameron"], 4),

     new MultiChoiceQues(2, "What is the Capital of Brazil?", ["São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Brasília", "Salvador"], 3),

     new MultiChoiceQues(3, "Who won the French open 2016 in Men’s Single  category?", ["Novak Djokovic", "Andy Murray", "Rafael Nadal"], 1)
    ];

    function ShowAllQues(){
       document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=content;
    }

    function ShowAllAns(){
       $(".answer").addClass("green");
    }
```

```css
    body {
         background: #f2f2f3;
         font-family: 'Century Gothic';
         font-weight: 100;
         color: #0193b7;
        }

        ul{
          list-style:none;
        }

        ul li:hover{
          cursor:pointer;
          color:#5bb12f;
        }

        #container {
          border: 10px solid #293e6a;
          padding: 0 0 20px 30px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #c4c4c4;
        }

        p {
          font-family: 'Eras ITC';
          color: #e792b5;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-weight: normal;
        }

        .flyingButton {
          position: fixed;
          right: 18px;
          top: 80px;
          height: 50px;
          width: 100px;
          background: #293e6a;
          border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
          border: none;
          color: #f2f2f2;
          cursor:pointer;
        }
        .green{
                color: #1B6F1B;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .flyingButton:hover {
          background: #0193b7;
        }

        .flyingButton:focus{
          outline:0;
        }
```

```html
    <body onload="ShowAllQues();">
       <div id="container">
       </div>
    <input type="button" value="Answers" class="flyingButton" onclick="ShowAllAns(); 
    return false;">
```

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr:

- Add Class `<ul class="answerChoicesGroup">`
- Replace `return content` with `this.answer = theAns;`
- Create `var` getting `answerChoicesGroup`: `answerChoicesGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('answerChoicesGroup');`
- Insert in `showAllAns()` the following:

.

```
function ShowAllAns() {
    /* Highlight all the correct answers */
    for (i = 0; i < allQues.length; i++) {
        // Get the current answer group
        var answerGroup = answerChoicesGroup[i],
            // Access the correct radio input answer by getting the answer index from `allQues`
            correctAnswer = answerGroup.children[allQues[i].answer - 1];

        // Do whatever you'd like with `correctAnswer`
        correctAnswer.firstElementChild.checked = true;
        correctAnswer.classList.add('answer');
    }
}
```

---

#### Explanation

You are on the right track by `return content`. Instead of that, (which won't `return content` because you have the keyword `new`) I just did `this.answer = theAns`. `answer` can be any word you'd like.

The way to access `answer` would be like any object. i.e.

```
var muiltipleChoiceQuestion = new MultiChoiceQues(1, "Who is Prime Minister of England?", ["Obama", "Blair", "Brown", "Cameron"], 4),

alert(muiltipleChoiceQuestion.answer) // result: 4
```

The next thing I did was, added a class name to all the `ul's` called `answerChoicesGroup`, and created a variable for that too.

In `showAllAns()` function, I iterated through `allQues`, and accessed the correct answer by:

1. Get the current answer group. (`var answerGroup`)
2. Access the correct radio input answer by getting the answer index from `allQues`. (`var correctAnswer`)
3. Do whatever you'd like with `correctAnswer`.

Here's the code:

Here's how you would do it:

#### JSFiddle

```js
var content = "";

function MultiChoiceQues(theSeq, theQues, theChoices, theAns) {
  content += '<p>' + theQues + '</p> <ul class="answerChoicesGroup">';

  theChoices.forEach(function(eachChoice) {
    content += '<li><input type="radio" name="' + theSeq + '"/> ' + eachChoice + '</li>';
  });
  content += '</ul>';
  this.answer = theAns;
}

var allQues = [
    new MultiChoiceQues(1, "Who is Prime Minister of England?", ["Obama", "Blair", "Brown", "Cameron"], 4),
    new MultiChoiceQues(2, "What is the Capital of Brazil?", ["São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Brasília", "Salvador"], 3),
    new MultiChoiceQues(3, "Who won the French open 2016 in Men’s Single category?", ["Novak Djokovic", "Andy Murray", "Rafael Nadal"], 1)
  ],
  answerChoicesGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('answerChoicesGroup');

function ShowAllQues() {
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = content;
}

function ShowAllAns() {
  /* Highlight all the correct answers */
  for (i = 0; i < allQues.length; i++) {
    // Get the current answer group
    var answerGroup = answerChoicesGroup[i],
      // Access the correct radio input answer by getting the answer index from `allQues`
      correctAnswer = answerGroup.children[allQues[i].answer - 1];

    // Do whatever you'd like with `correctAnswer`
    correctAnswer.firstElementChild.checked = true;
    correctAnswer.classList.add('answer');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #f2f2f3;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #0193b7;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5bb12f;
}
#container {
  border: 10px solid #293e6a;
  padding: 0 0 20px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #c4c4c4;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Eras ITC';
  color: #e792b5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.flyingButton {
  position: fixed;
  right: 18px;
  top: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #293e6a;
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  border: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flyingButton:hover {
  background: #0193b7;
}
.flyingButton:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.answer {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body onload="ShowAllQues();">
  <div id="container">
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="Answers" class="flyingButton" onclick="ShowAllAns();">
</body>
```